# SQL Server windows authentication Login failure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have installed SQL Server 2008 in my pc having windows 8 version and after installation while i am trying to login to SQL Server using windows authentication it is showing error as shown below

[image]

And I tried as shown below

[Resolving SQL Server Connection Error 26](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h24S8xXC94A)

And i got the below error while i tried the above suggestion

[image]

Comment: As the error indicates, you need to look at the event log.

Comment: This won't solve your issue but you shouldn't use services.msc. Use SQL Server Configuration Manager. And you should have a look at the contents of the SQL Server errorlog. It should give you some hints as to why the SQL Server can't start.

Answer (score 0):

During the installation, you didn't Add the current user as Windows Authenticated User, you need to re-install the SQL Server, then add the current user as one of the Authenticated User

Comment: Why the downvote? He's probably right although there might be ways to do it without a reinstall